# split the string value stored in a variable by a batch file

Tags: windows, string, batch-file, character-encoding

I want to write a batch file on windows environment to store a file name into a variable and split it into 4 different variables.

For example if my file name is mferuntime20140409154525632.dat .I want to store 2014 in a variable W,04 in X,09 in Y,154525 in Z.

I am storing file name into a variable named "File" by following command:

For %%File in ("C:\Program Files\Common Files\McAfee\Engine\mferuntime20140409154525632.dat") do echo %%File

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm try this:

```
For %%File in ("C:\Program Files\Common Files\McAfee\Engine\mferuntime20140409154525632.dat") do set file=%%File

set file=%file:~10,17%
set W=%file:~0,4%
set X=%file:~4,2%
set Y=%file:~6,2%
set Z=%file:~8,6%
```

Which worked perfectly for me.

Comment: I am retrieving file name by following command line
For %%File in ("C:\Program Files\Common Files\McAfee\Engine\mferuntime20140409154525632.dat") do echo %%File

Comment: Then look at my edit. Remember to mark my answer as correct if it helped

Comment: unable to echo (and compare with number) the values of variables File,W,X,Y,Z

Comment: I would replace `set file=%file:~10,17%` with `set file=%file:*2=2%`, assuming the filename contains a bunch of letters, followed by a Date-Time-string (it replaces the string <firstChar>-to-"2" with "2" only, effectly removing trailing letters.